# C# "scanf" with Custom Console

Tags: c#, console, scanf

My program is a Windows Form Application in C#.

I have an interpreter/compiler IDE w/c basically runs a custom Language through a customized console window.

When interpreting input lines like "scanf", how do pause the interpreting while the user doesn't press enter?

Sample custom code to parse:

```
1     VAR x AS INT
2     START
3        INPUT: x
4        OUTPUT: x
5     STOP
```

For example, in those lines, when my program processes line 3, it doesn't process the other lines until the user inputs something and presses enter.

Pseudo-Snippet for line by line parsing:

```
foreach (string line in inputCode)
{
   LineType lineType = line.getType();

   if(lineType.InputStatement)
   {
   //wait for input here
   }
   else if(lineType.OutputStatement)
   {
   //analyze output code here
   }
   else if(lineType.AssignmentStatement)
   {
   //do Evaluation here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make each method raise an event to fire the next line.
The `INPUT` method should fire that event after the user presses enter.

Comment: Basically, convert your procedural code to async.  You can make that simpler using C# 5 async or using iterators

Answer (score 1):

[Console.Readline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx) or [Console.ReadKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey.aspx) will allow you to read input from the console simillar to scanf.

Comment: I'm not using a console application. I'm using a Form as a customized console.

Comment: Did you develop the customized console.  Is it sitting ontop of another control?

Comment: The console is basically a form with a textbox. It's triggered by an MDI Form.

Comment: Is the usage model.  User enters a complete program and then it is run line for line.